# Display API Call in URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

how do I display my API call to the URL? I am using `axios.get` and passing in params from components, like this https://mydomain/search?keyword=blahblah&filter2=xxx, etc. I can view the API URL using inspect-> network tab. I would like to display the API call with parameters to the URL so the user can bookmark the search. My APP.js code is like below:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    keyword:'',
    filter1:''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.runSearch(this.state.keyword, this.state.filter1);
  }

  runSearch = async (keyword, filter1) => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://mydomain/search', {
      params: {
        keyword: keyword,
        filter1: filter1
      }
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 2 terms **route** and **API** both have different purposes. For re-direction we use **routes** and yeah we do append **query params** to **routes** with different methods depending upon the framework, you're working on.

**API** is normally written to get data from the server it doesn't suppose to provide **redirection**. 
So, you may use the `this.props.history.push` method if using **react-router** in your app or simple **JS** property `window.location.href` in your event-handler functions.

`window.location.href` is a property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser. Changing the value of the property will redirect the page.

**window.location.href** = 'http://www.google.com'; `//Will take you to Google.`

Answer (score 0):

So the confusion is that GET requests are not *all* in the URL bar. Yes, that is initiating a GET request, but every variation of a request can be done asynchronously via JavaScript, which has no effect on the browser's URL.

In this case, you'll want to use the browser's API to change the URL directly. React Router should have a method for this (`this.props.history.push('/foo')`) or you could do it with vanilla JS (`history.pushState(state, pageTitle, url)`).

Comment: Thanks. so I have to add this.props.history.push() to each component event handler function?

Comment: @user788448 That could work. Or perhaps you can hook into React Router's global state and have it update from the one location. This is all based on what your desired results are.